# does anyone know how to acces an android background process from an other activity as its own?

Tags: android-activity, network-programming

does anyone know how to acces an android  background process from an other activity as its own?

for example i have an network connection on my MainActivity but want to send data via that from an other activity.

how to handle that.

Thanks in ahead.

Dyon

Comment: http://saigeethamn.blogspot.nl/2009/08/android-developer-tutorial-for_31.html

http://android-er.blogspot.nl/2011/08/return-result-to-onactivityresult.html

Comment: I fond 2  links  that give the answer http://saigeethamn.blogspot.nl/2009/08/android-developer-tutorial-for_31.html

http://android-er.blogspot.nl/2011/08/return-result-to-onactivityresult.html      so solution found